# Is it possible to load a php file in codeigniter dynamically?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to load a php file dynamically. for example i have a website and i added new php file and it will load the new php file. is it possible without going through controller?

Comment: your question is not clear you want to load custom php code, not a part of codeigniter ? so you can use exec function in php or you are write cURL request.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Yes, I want to load a php file that is not part of codeigniter. Is it possible to load or include a view or php file that has no controller but can perform CRUD operations? @ArsalanAkhtar

Comment: yes you just send request to curl.

$this->load->library('curl');
$result = $this->curl->simple_get('http://YOUR_CODE_URL.com/');
you can pass your result in view.

Comment: But codeIgniter-cURL is Deprecated already.. [Github] (https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if you are not using cURL.

```
file_get_contents('http://YOUR_CODE_URL.com/send.php?'.$getdata, false, $context);
```

Furthermore, the method defaults to GET so you don't even need to set options, nor create a stream context. So, for this particular situation, you could simply call file_get_contents with the first parameter if you wish.

Comment: Thanks!! @ArslanAkhtar